# Why does Winstonjs ExceptionHandler silence my node errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, exception, winston

I've got a program written in Node in which I use Winstonjs for logging. I also have an exceptionHandler so that the node exceptions/errors also reach my logs. I now have a problem though. When I run the script from the command line using `node index.js` (instead of [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)) the script ends silently when it has an error.

Have a look at my example code below. I added three `console.log()`s which try to log an undefined variable. When I run the script using `node index.js` it gives me a `ReferenceError` for the first wrong `console.log(undefinedVariable)` as expected. When I now remove that first and/or the second `console.log`, the script ends silently.

```
"use strict";

let winston = require('winston');
const path = require('path');

const PRODUCTION = false;

// LOGGING
const myFormat = winston.format.printf(info => {
    return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

console.log(undefinedVariable);  // THIS GIVES A REFERENCE ERROR

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), myFormat),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({filename: 'logs/error.log', level: 'error'}),
        new winston.transports.File({filename: 'logs/combined.log'}),
    ],
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/exceptions.log' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs/combined.log' })
    ]
});

console.log(undefinedVariable);  // THIS DOES NOT GIVE A REFERENCE ERROR, BUT ENDS THE SCRIPT SILENTLY

if (!PRODUCTION) {
    // If we're not in production then also log to the `console`
    logger.add(new winston.transports.Console(
        {format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), myFormat), level: 'debug'}
    ));
}

console.log(undefinedVariable);  // THIS ALSO DOES NOT GIVE A REFERENCE ERROR, BUT ENDS THE SCRIPT SILENTLY

function log(message, level='debug'){
    // Levels: error, warn, info, verbose, debug, silly
    const e = new Error();
    const regex = /\((.*):(\d+):(\d+)\)$/
    const match = regex.exec(e.stack.split("\n")[2]);
    let log_source = path.basename(match[1]) + ':' + match[2];  // eg: index.js:285

    if (typeof message === 'object'){
        message = JSON.stringify(message);
    }
    logger[level](log_source + ' - ' + message);
}
```

I'm running Winstonjs version `3.0.0-rc5`. I know it's not the final 3.0 release yet, but I guess I'm simply making a mistake here.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you see [Handling Uncaught Exceptions with winston doc](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#handling-uncaught-exceptions-with-winston)

you can set `exitOnError = false`

> By default, winston will exit after logging an uncaughtException. If this is not the behavior you want, set exitOnError = false

And also add to yours transports `new winston.transports.Console({ handleExceptions: true })` for show it in console.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. However, the problem is not that it exits on the error. The problem is that it fails silently. It does log the error to the log file, but not in the console. I simply want to see the error in the console as well.

Comment: @kramer65 Have you try adding a new transport for console? Like: ```new winston.transports.Console({
      handleExceptions: true
    })```

Comment: Awesome, that was eactly what I was looking for! If you add that to your answer I can accept it!

Comment: have same problem as Kramer65, this solution works.